# How can I easily convert a large number of pictures from RAW to scaled down JPG?

Tags: software, raw, jpeg, batch

I have a collection of shots from the same session in RAW and want to covert all of them to JPG. Each one should have a curve applied, then be scaled and sharpened using the same settings.

What is the best way to do this? Can I automate PhotoShop (or alternative) to perform the same steps over a number of pictures?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Could you please specify this in your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open your folder containing the photographs in Adobe Bridge, then in the menu go:
"Tools" -> "Photoshop" -> "Image Processor".
(Entries translated.)

Set your JPEG quality and maximum resolution per side (aspect ratio will be retained), click go and wait.

Note:
Bridge comes with Photoshop for those who do not know that.

---

Also, if you want to apply similar settings to all photographs, you can copy over settings in Bridge. Right click the RAW and it is an option in the second level of the menu.

Answer (score 2):

[Aperture 3](http://www.apple.com/aperture/) could be used for batch conversion. You import the RAW pictures into a library. When importing you could have a set of pre-defined settings. Choose `Import Settings -> Adjusment Preset`. Select the preset you like. If there is no one that you like, you could edit/create your own preset. During the import process it is also possible to do a backup of your files, which I think is handy. Of course you could do simple things like renaming pictures etc. When you have them all imported, you could export them at once or apply your adjustment.

The process is semi-automatic, you will have to select the settings before import and the choose your settings when exporting. If you want to automate everything, I suggest using the `Automator` application that is provided with Mac OS X.

I use Aperture 3 for batch processing and a like a lot. It is cheaper than PhotoShop. It is available for Mac OS X.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was about performing batch operations on RAW files and conversions into JPEG. When answering, don't just look at other answers, make sure you are actually answering the question.

Comment: OK, I have tried to clarify the answer. For me this was obvious in the context of mentioning a software that could help with batch conversion ;-) I hope that it is clear now.

Comment: @jrista is this better? ;-)

Comment: Yup, much better. :)

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have any extra photo editing programs I used iPhoto to do this.
Open iPhoto with the option key held down. This gives you the option to create a new library. Create a temporary one somewhere where it will be easy to find and delete it later. Import all the Raw Pictures into the new library. Export them all in the required format. Quit and delete the library.

Comment: Nice because it's a free alternative.  It may not be the *best* answer, per se, but it's a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

On OSX, there is a fast, free and easy option.  Go into terminal and navigate to the folder containing your RAW photos.  For Nikon NEF images, run this command:

```
# Convert RAW to JPG
for i in *.NEF; do sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 70  $i --out $i.jpg;done
```

The `-s formatOptions` setting specifies the JPG quality.

Man for `sips` here: https://ss64.com/osx/sips.html

Also useful, if your files are in nested folders, you can run this first to bring everything up to your current folder:

```
# Move children to current folder
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \; 

# Remove Empty Folders
rm -r -- ./*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with [Digikam](http://digikam.org).

Go to `Tools > Batch Raw converter` and add the files, then apply your curves and the like. (Tried with 2.0.0-rc, newest version is 2.5.0.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with Adobe Camera RAW. It's very fast and you can set some processing settings on it.

Drag and drop all of your RAW files to Photoshop and they'll open in Adobe Camera RAW. You can set the size and colour setting using the link at the bottom/middle of the screen.

Select all the images in the sidebar and apply the curves and processing settings you want and then use the 'Save Images...' button in the bottom left.

Answer (score 1):

[ACDSee Pro](http://www.acdsee.com/en/products/acdsee-pro-5) is a good tool. It is available for Windows and Mac OS X. I used this for many years. It has good batch processing engine. It is very handy to do these type of batch conversion, batch  re-size, batch rename, batch color correction etc.

Answer (score 1):

On windows for Canon: Digital Photo Professional. GUI application.

On Linux for any camera: [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) + the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) package and a little work in shell.

Answer (score 0):

For quickly converting and resizing images I use Faststone - very quick and freeware.

http://www.faststone.org/

Comment: Faststone doesn't support RAW files :( but I use it for JPEG resizing.

Comment: According to the website it *does* support RAW.  If not, then why would you suggest it for converting RAW to JPG?

Comment: FWIW, faststone uses dcraw for the conversion, with default options. That's not particularly flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with **Adobe Lightroom**. You can process catalog, set of photos or photo by clicking "File > Export.." and set not only dimension of photos but also add watermark, sharpen them for printing or screen, rename and much more.

It's also great tool for editing photos and applying same styles for all photos take literally seconds.

You can check exporting video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7z89b5EgXs).